# nbitcoin Get balance

Tags: c#, nbitcoin

Try to get balance :

```
var bitcoinPrivateKey = new BitcoinSecret("xxxx");
var network = bitcoinPrivateKey.Network;
var address = bitcoinPrivateKey.GetAddress();

var client = new QBitNinjaClient(network);
var balance = client.GetBalance(address).Result;
```

but i get a error `One or more errors occurred` in line `var balance = client.GetBalance(address).Result;` . Private key is valid. Previously, everything worked well, but now not. Where my mistake ?

Edit:
i wanted to check inner exc

```
try
{
  var client = new QBitNinjaClient(network);

  var balance = client.GetBalance(address).Result;

  Console.WriteLine(balance);
}
 catch(Exception e) {
  if (e.InnerException !=null)
      Console.WriteLine("error"+e.InnerException.Message);
 }
```

but now he didnt go to exception, he show me balance. what could be the problem ? why doesn't it always work ?